# Manipulating String Perl SVs in C

Tags: c, string, perl

I'm currently trying to do some string based manipulation in an attempt to speed up a section of traditional Perl code. The original Perl code looks like

```
my $value = 'abCdE';
my $uc_value = uc($value);
```

I've looked at the Perl guts API and it seems that I can accomplish this using `toUPPER()` but this works on a single char at a time. I seem to be missing how you can loop through the backing char array, uppercasing each letter & then assigning it into a new SV.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Will `toUPPER` handle Unicode (and different locales) the way `uc` does? Do you have hard proof that a single call to `uc` is really the bottleneck of your application? (I suppose it could be in a loop, but I honestly doubt there's much you can do to speed it up.)

Comment: So I did a massive simplification of the larger issue at hand which is causing a bottle neck & has been optimised in pure-Perl as much as it can be. The crux of the matter is that my re-implementation has boiled down to a loop where I need to iterate over a stack of Strings (SVs), remove `-` and convert all characters to upper case. This was done in Perl using `tr/a-z\055/A-Z/d`. It would seem to make more sense in C to iterate through all characters in a SV, remove the `-` if detected and `toUPPER()` all characters. I just don't have a clue how to do that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl does not provide a lot of its functionality to C level extensions, uppercasing is apparently one of those features. At best, you can look at how the core [implements](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/HEAD:/pp.c#l3834) this, but it's really not all that pretty.

Comment: ZOMG! That was exactly the example I was looking for but I just couldn't find where the Perl functions are coded. Thanks @leon-timmermans